# How to get date posted by datepicker?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this in view:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date, inst){
        $(this).parent('form').submit();
    }
});

<form method="post" name="datepickerForm">
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
</form>
Date Posted: @ViewBag.PostedDate
```

in the controller, I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? datepickerForm) {
    if(datepickerForm.HasValue) // this is always null
        ViewBag.PostedDate = datepickerForm.Value;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `div` for the datepicker?  Shouldn't it be an `input`?  `<input id="datepicker" />`

Comment: @RocketHazmat, the page contains a calendar, when user clicks on it, it displays data for that date. That's why I don't think the `input textbox` is necessary since that'll introduce an extra click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using both `div` for display and `input textbox` for posting date back.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date, inst){
        $('#datepickerTxt').val(date);
        $(this).parent('form').submit();
    }
});

<form method="post" name="datepickerForm">
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    <input type="text" id="datepickerTxt" name="datepickerTxt" />
</form>
Date Posted: @ViewBag.PostedDate
```

in the controller, I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(string datepickerTxt) {
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(datepickerTxt)
        ViewBag.PostedDate = datepickerTxt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `div` to an `input`.

```
<input id="datepicker" name="date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the below code in view

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
onSelect: function (date, inst){
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
} 
 });

 <form method="post" name="datepickerForm">
 <input id="datepicker"/>
  </form>
```

have the below code in controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? datepicker) {
//datepicker id of input element
    ViewBag.PostedDate = datepicker;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<input id="datepicker" name="date" />
```

instead of

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Read [this](http://yassershaikh.com/introduction-to-jquery-date-picker-in-asp-net-mvc/), the article demonstrates the correct way on using datepicker and sending/posting the data back to the controller.